# Notifications for the same messages delivered over and over again on Monterey

Tags: messages

This is infuriating: I'll receive a message, notification pops up, I click on it, read it, then move on. Then some time later another notification for that same message will pop up again, again I'll head over to make sure that reading the message somehow "sticks" this time. Then some time later another notification pops up, etc. I tried restarting the Messages app but the problem persists. I've been receiving the same six notifications for the past two hours now...

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar in the past and deleted the message and did a restart of the device.